# My computer shut down by itself

Tags: shutdown

My computer is 7 years old (with small changes). It shut down by itself and I think  there is a problem with the temperature.

- **CPU Type**: DualCore Intel Pentium D 945, 3416 MHz (17 x 201)
- **Motherboard Name**: Gigabyte GA-8I945PLGE-RH  (3 PCI, 2 PCI-E x1, 1
  PCI-E x16, 2 DDR2 DIMM, Audio, Gigabit LAN)
- **Video Adapter**: Radeon X300/X550/X1050 Series Secondary  (512 MB)

From the beginning the temperature was high and when I started a program raises at 92-95. I don't know a lot about computers.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

(Sorry for my English)

Comment: Purchase thermal paste and an new heatsink + fan.  Your talking about $30-40 investment.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, a temperature of 82°C is hot for a Pentium D 945. And your motherboard (GA-8I945PLGE-RH) appears to have an auto-shutdown if the temperature pops above a set amount (depending on your settings about 100°C) - here are the BIOS options.

Have you opened the computer case? Does your CPU fan still work? Is it caked in dust and grime? The first thing you should do is carefully open the case and use [Compressed Gas Duster like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004E2MF5S) to blow away all the gunk and dust that has accumulated in the case and especially on the fans.

Try that first!

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to clean it. The best way is to buy a can of compressed air, open the case and give it a good dusting. Focus on the fans, especially the one over the CPU.

If that does not work, you may have to change the thermal paste between the CPU and its heat sink. This is not hard to do and there are many tutorials around but if you are not comfortable playing with your hardware ask a geek friend or take it to a professional.

Comment: Make sure the fans do **not** spin freely when you hit them with the compressed air. If they do you may permanently damage your motherboard.

Comment: @Hennes seriously? I did not know that and I have cleaned a fair number of fans in my time. How would it damage the MB, not the fan but the MB? By spinning in the wrong direction? Whacking against something?

Comment: I agree, I've always cleaned the fans with compressed air and let them spin freely (just a short time, though... about 1 sec maybe), and haven't had any issues in the past 7 years.

Comment: Many fans are the same as generators. Apply power and it will spin. (2 pins fans). Spin it and it will generate power. Spins it ways too fast using compressed air and you might get a problem.

Comment: perhaps by generating some voltage in the pins, as the fan will act like a wind power generator... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrVCUvyRX7U

Comment: Yup. @Juha: Usually it is not problem. Just as not grounding yourself before doing maintenance usually is not a problem. However the safe thing is not to let them spin freely.

Comment: @woliveirajr Ah, that's interesting

Comment: thanks for answering... i dont know if it matters... but i made a mistake.... the temperature when my computer is open and i dont do anything is 55-60 but when i start a game or "big" programs then starts the overheating...

Comment: i opened it somemtimes to clean it but probably i didnt pay much attention.... also when i removed the cpu... the thermal paste was dry and not very well placed..... i will check both,cleaning and th thermal paste..... thanks again

Comment: @mourgos if you have removed the CPU, you MUST apply new thermal paste, whatever you do, do NOT return the CPU to its place without new paste. As for the temp, no worries, we understood that that is the temperature under heavy load. PS. akou mourgos... :)